# How to reorder dimensions?

Tags: 3d, netcdf, dimension, permute

I am working on precipitation data. I need to rearrange dimensions in a NetCDF file. The dimensions in my file are in `(time, lat, lon)` order. I need them in `(lat, lon, time)` order.

I tried the following:

```
ncpdq -a lat,lon,time infile.nc outfile.nc
```

now, I got order of dimension I wanted which is `(lat, lon, time)`.

However, the `lat` dimension becomes `UNLIMITED` which is wrong. The time dimension should be the `UNLIMITED` dimension. This is what I got:

```
dimensions: 
   lon = 720 ;
   lat = UNLIMITED ; // (360 currently)
   time = 1404 ;
```

What should I do to reorder the dimensions from `(time, lat, lon)`  to `(lat, lon, time)`?

Answer (score 3):

I did a check, and to me it seems the reorder works. I checked the file info with `ncdump -h inputfile.nc` and `ncdump -h outputfile.nc` and the comparison is like this:
[image: Comparison of file info before and after the re-order]

As you see, the re-ordering has been made and the first dimension, which is the `latc` in my case, becomes unlimited.

Fortunately, you can do this to fix the latitude:

```
ncks --fix_rec_dmn lat output.nc -o outfixed.nc ; mv outfixed.nc outputfile.nc
```

and to unlimit time again:

```
ncks --mk_rec_dmn time outputfile.nc -o outunlim.nc ; mv outunlim.nc outputfile.nc
```

So now the outputfile, should be ok.